# не работает перевод градусов, минут, секунд в радианы, формула не приводит к нужному результату

Tags: python

Задание - Напишите программу, переводящую градусы в радианы. Градусная мера
задаётся в виде трёх целочисленных величин: deg, min, sec.
Программа должна выводить два числа: градусы с долями и радианы.

Нашел формулу радианы = градусы + (минуты + секунды/60)/60
Но ответ не совпадает с калькулятором радиан, не понимаю в чем причина, вроде всё просто...

```
import math
print ('Введите градусы')
deg = int(input ())
print ('Введите секунды')
sec = int(input ())
print ('Введите минуты')
min = int(input ())
rad = deg + (min+sec/60) / 60
print (f'Градусы = {deg}', f'Радианы = {rad}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Нашел формулу` - это вряд ли. Приведённое выражение - получение значения "градусы с долями". А их уже переводить в радианы, как в школе проходили.

```
fdeg = deg + (min+sec/60) / 60
rad = fdeg * math.pi / 180
```